# python cache functions seems to be slower

Tags: caching, python-3.11

I am tring to use `@cache` decorator to make functions faster. I have made a program that compares the run time of some functions that calculate factorials and combinations (with the recursive formulae and the factorial one), and it seems that the 'cache' methods in most cases are slower than the 'normal'. Maybe I am making something wrong?. Another thing is that, when I quit the if in the function C6, it appears to be slower. I gonna thank anyone that can explain I have made something wrong.

```
from functools import cache, lru_cache
from time import time
import sys

sys.setrecursionlimit (5000)

def factorial1 (n: int) -> int:
    if n == 1 or n == 0:
        return 1
    else: 
        return n * factorial1 (n-1)

@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def factorial2 (n: int) -> int:
    if n == 1 or n == 0:
        return 1
    else: 
        return n * factorial2 (n-1)

a1 = time ()
r = factorial1 (1000)
r = factorial1 (999)
r = factorial1 (50)
r = factorial1 (30)
a1 = 1000 * (time () - a1)

a2 = time ()
r = factorial2 (1000)
r = factorial2 (999)
r = factorial2 (50)
r = factorial2 (30)
a2 = 1000 * (time () - a2)

print ()
print ("calcule 6 factorials: ")
print ("\twithout cache: {}".format(a1))
print ("\twith cache: {}".format(a2))

def C1 (n, m) -> int:
    if n > m:
        return 0
    elif m == 0 or m == n:
        return 1
    else:
        return C1 (n-1, m-1) + C1 (n-1, m)

@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def C2 (n, m) -> int:
    if n > m:
        return 0
    elif m == 0 or m == n:
        return 1
    else:
        return C2 (n-1, m-1) + C2 (n-1, m)

def C3 (n, m) -> int:
    if n > m:
        return 0
    else:
        return factorial1 (n) // factorial1 (n-m)

@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def C4 (n, m) -> int:
    if n > m:
        return 0
    else:
        return factorial2 (n) // factorial2 (n-m)

def C5 (n, m) -> int:
    if n > m:
        return 0
    else:
        return factorial1 (n) // factorial1 (n-m)

@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def C6 (n, m) -> int:
    if n > m:
        return 0
    else:
        return factorial2 (n) // factorial2 (n-m)

def proof(fun) -> float:
    a = time ()
    r = fun (400, 300)
    r = fun (800, 300)
    r = fun (322, 183)
    r = fun (1000, 200)
    r = fun (716, 526)
    return 1000 * (time () - a)

print ()
print ("calculate 5 combinations, equial parameters and same order: ")
print ("\tformulae by recursion, without cache: {}".format(proof (C1)))
print ("\tformulae by recursion, with cache: {}".format(proof (C2)))
print ("\tformulae by factorial without cache, without cache: {}".format(proof (C3)))
print ("\tformulae by factorial without cache, with cache: {}".format(proof (C4)))
print ("\tformulae by factorial with cache, without cache: {}".format(proof (C5)))
print ("\tformulae by factorial with cache, with cache: {}".format(proof (C6)))
print ()
print ("By this, it seems that the @cache and @lru_cahce decorator don't do the methods to run more effitiently, despite the fact that @cache functions stores previous results.")
print ()
print ("Something interesting: if the 'if statement' is removed from the function definition, the function takes more time to finish.")

@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def C7 (n, m) -> int:
    return factorial2 (n) // factorial2 (n-m)

print ()
print ("formulae by factorial with cache, with cache")
print ("\tnormal definition: {}".format(proof (C6)))
print ("\tremoving if from the definition: {}".format(proof (C7)))
```